# How to get components for building a silent install

Tags: chocolatey, silent-installer, choco

So when running an executable, you know how there are a bunch of parameters you can check (like include a desktop icon), how do i get a list of available components for an executable, so i can pass these components to the executable from the command line? I researched and came across, silent arguments, and you can append /components on the end of the command to do this:

```
SomeExecut.exe /COMPONENTS = "comp1,comp2"
```

Further Explanation:
My final goal is to use chocolatey to install packages onto machines, however, the defaults dont always select the properties we need, i want to create custom choco package with an executable and pass the appropriate parameters to the choco install MYPACKAGE.

Any other suggestions are appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For open source Chocolatey and outside Chocolatey itself, the answer is you would research ***each*** software installer to find them. Each installer is built differently. We like to say that each piece of software is a special snowflake.

There are 20+ different known installer types. Chocolatey knows about most of them. Most of them don't have much to offer, like [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html).

[InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline) has "COMPONENTS" like you are seeing. What exactly is available is defined by each installer. In a future version of [Package Builder](https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-create-packages-from-installers) (part of Chocolatey for Business), it is going to automatically extract these and provide them as [package parameters](https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-parse-package-parameters-argument) for you to use.

MSI (Windows Installer) has [MSI Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370912.aspx). [Package Builder](https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-create-packages-from-installers) already extracts these and adds them to the install script as a comment and to the package description as options to pass as [`--install-arguments`](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-upgrade#options-and-switches).

#### Package Builder Extraction

To give you an idea, this is what right click create package on the Puppet-Agent for Windows MSI will get you as part of the fully unattended software deployment package that is created in about 5 seconds:

```
<description>Puppet-Agent

### Package Specific
#### Installer Properties
The following install arguments can be passed:
 * `ALLUSERS`
 * `PUPPET_AGENT_ACCOUNT_DOMAIN`
 * `PUPPET_AGENT_ACCOUNT_USER`
 * `PUPPET_AGENT_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD`
 * `PUPPET_MASTER_SERVER`
 * `PUPPET_AGENT_ENVIRONMENT`
 * `PUPPET_AGENT_CERTNAME`
 * `PUPPET_CA_SERVER`
 * `PUPPET_AGENT_STARTUP_MODE`
 * `INSTALLDIR`
 * `INSTALLDIR_X86`

To append install arguments to the current silent arguments passed to the installer, use `--install-arguments="''"` or `--install-arguments-sensitive="''"`. To completely override the silent arguments with your own, also pass `--override-arguments`.
 Example: `choco install packageId [other options] --install-arguments="'PROPERTY=value PROPERTY2=value2'"`
To have choco remember parameters on upgrade, be sure to set `choco feature enable -n=useRememberedArgumentsForUpgrades`.
</description>
```

To pull that out to markdown, this is what it looks like:

**Package Specific**

**Installer Properties**

The following install arguments can be passed:

- `ALLUSERS`
- `PUPPET_AGENT_ACCOUNT_DOMAIN`
- `PUPPET_AGENT_ACCOUNT_USER`
- `PUPPET_AGENT_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD`
- `PUPPET_MASTER_SERVER`
- `PUPPET_AGENT_ENVIRONMENT`
- `PUPPET_AGENT_CERTNAME`
- `PUPPET_CA_SERVER`
- `PUPPET_AGENT_STARTUP_MODE`
- `INSTALLDIR`
- `INSTALLDIR_X86`

To append install arguments to the current silent arguments passed to the installer, use `--install-arguments="''"` or `--install-arguments-sensitive="''"`. To completely override the silent arguments with your own, also pass `--override-arguments`.
 Example: `choco install packageId [other options] --install-arguments="'PROPERTY=value PROPERTY2=value2'"`
To have choco remember parameters on upgrade, be sure to set `choco feature enable -n=useRememberedArgumentsForUpgrades`.

Comment: I am following a similar post to try and get the various install options, and i came across using Git-2.15.1.2-64-bit.exe /SAVEINF="C:\git.inf" to generate what looks like the file with the options im after. How would i use these options in chocolatey? Or reference this .inf file? Is it possible?

Comment: @BLang From http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline: it appears you can use `/LOADINF`. So it would be `choco install git --install-arguments "'/LOADINF=C:\git.inf'" --override-arguments`. If you need to use `"` in your args, things are shell dependent, see https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-reference#how-to-pass-options-switches